# How to disable the interactive 3D view and prevent Asymptote from generating raster output?

Tags: asymptote

I don't need the interactive 3D view because it will be viewed on papers. I just want to draw vector graphics 3D objects.

For the following code, it seems that Asymptote rasterizes the output. Is there any method to avoid this? I am using `pdflatex->asy->pdflatex` sequence.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,2,center=true);
size(5cm);
size3(3cm,5cm,8cm);
draw(unitbox);
dot(unitbox,red);
label("$O$",(0,0,0),NW);
label("(1,0,0)",(1,0,0),S);
label("(0,1,0)",(0,1,0),E);
label("(0,0,1)",(0,0,1),Z);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried this [info](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153048/87876) but it does not seem to work.

## Edit

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.interactiveView=false;
settings.batchView=false;
settings.render=0;
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,2,center=true);
size(5cm);
size3(3cm,5cm,8cm);
draw(unitbox);
dot(unitbox,red);
label("$O$",(0,0,0),NW);
label("(1,0,0)",(1,0,0),S);
label("(0,1,0)",(0,1,0),E);
label("(0,0,1)",(0,0,1),Z);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

I still get the interactive 3D view.

Comment: strangely once the 3D view is activated in Acrobat Reader, the edges do not look rasterized anymore (tested at 3200% magnification)

Comment: I guess you are looking for [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212283/121799).

Comment: another potential duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9210/asymptote-generated-3d-raster-image

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I do not know what you want to achieve nor why asymptote is written as it is written, but according to the answer you can get vector graphics with `settings.render=0;`.

Comment: You probably just did not overwrite the old file when you "still get the interactive 3D view". Can you try creating a completely new file such that asymptote is not tempted to just use the old one? (This is one of the reasons why I use `asypictureB`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting Charles Staats III excellent [Asymptote tutorial](https://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf) (p. 52),

> By  default,  when  Asymptote  does  3d  stuff  and outputs a pdf file, the 3d information will be embedded in the pdf file as prc data.This means that if the pdf file is viewed using Adobe Reader, it will be possible to rotate the image interactively.

What you are most likely looking for is the `settings.prc` option. Simply set it to `false` by using

```
settings.prc = false;
```

and you should get rid of the interactive 3D view.